# Finding the "M" in the ML inequality / Estimation Lemma.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I am trying to teach myself the residue theorem, and I think I am close to putting all of the pieces together. However, I am struggling with the ML inequality as it pertains to arcs that appear in my contour.

For example, consider:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2}}{(x^2 + 1)^2}dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2 + 1)^2 x^{1/2}}dx$

I can properly draw the contour, find the residues, and deal with the parts of the contour along the real axis. However, I cannot find the integrals of the circular arcs around the origin, such as:

$\int\frac{1}{(z^2 + 1)^2 z^{1/2}}dz$

which should approach $0$ as we let the radius of the arc go to either $0$ or $\infty$. I can find "solutions" to the overall problems, but nothing that goes into enough detail for me to follow finding the "M" in the ML inequality.

Comment: The two expressions with limits currently don't contain the limit variables $R$ and $r$, respectively. Could you modify your question?

Comment: @Bananach Sorry, I have corrected this.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense though. You cannot at the same time say $z:=Re^{i\theta}$ and then use $z$ as a dummy variable in an integral. (Hint: you should either replace the limits in the integral by circles (of radius $R$ and $r$, respectively) or write out the integral in terms of $\theta$, using the integration variable $\theta$)

Comment: OK, I have attempted another rewording.

Comment: You shouldn't leave the domain of integration blank either. A common way to write the integral would be "... such as $\int_{\gamma_{R}}f(z)$, where $\gamma_{R}$ is a circle of  radius R". Anyway, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large radii: bound modulus of integrand from above by $2R^{-9/2}$.

Small radii: bound modulus of integrand from above by $2r^{-1/2}$

Comment: Thank you, but could you please go into more detail? It is not obvious to me how you arrived at these boundaries.

Comment: Use $|1/z|=1/|z|$, $|zw|=|z||w|$, $|z^{s}|=|z|^s$, $|z+a|\geq |z|-|a|$ and $|z|-|a|\geq |z|/2$ (the last bound holds only when $|z|\geq 2|a|$ of course)

Comment: For the small radii, doesn't your solution go to infinity as $r \to 0$?

Comment: That's where the $ L $ comes into play (assuming I got the abbreviation ML right:L=length)